# Is there another way to apply the same style to multiple HTML elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a Web Application and I ran into an issue relating the **<link> element in HTML**. Basically, I tried to link my styless.css folder but the style was **not applying on the live server**.

**This is my HTML file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <title>Menu - Café</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- STYLE -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Mon-Café</h1>
            <p>Est. 2019</p>
            <!-- SECTION: Cafés -->
            <section>
                <h2>Cafés</h2>
            </section>
            <!-- SECTION: Sobremesas -->
            <section>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And this was my CSS file before any changes:**

```css
h1, h2, p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried editing the CSS file directly into Firefox Developer, these were my exact steps:

1. Inspect Element
2. Go to Style Editor
3. **Manually insert the code:**

```css
h1, h2, p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

As soon as I wrote that directly with Firefox Developer, it worked just fine, but with my styles.css file it was not working, only when there was a single element instead of multiple

**Then I tried another alternative for my CSS file:**

```css
h1, h2, p , .box{
    text-align: center;
}
```

I found about the **.box** ramdonly while searching for a fix for this, but that alternative worked just fine in the styles.css file, I don't know if that's the correct way or if I was doing something wrong the other way.

PS: I save my project multiple times so it can't be that

Comment: `.box` is a class selector - you don't have any elements with a `class="box"` attribute, at least not in the markup shown so far.

Comment: I'm not seeing any syntax errors. The link tag as shown assumes that you have a file called "styles.css" in the same directory as this page - is that correct?

Comment: As a follow-up, here's a jsFiddle confirming that your syntax is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1duxvye8/

Comment: @TiesonT. Hey Tieson, yes the file called styles.css is indeed in the same directory as this page - or in the same folder. I tried writing that same code but applying the style only in "<h1>", which worked just fine without using `.box`

Comment: You may need to perform a hard refresh (Cntrl + F5 on Windows, not sure what the equivalent macOS command is) while viewing the page - your browser could be caching the unstyled version. Otherwise, you'll want to check the Network tab in your brower's Developer Tools to see if you're getting a 404 response from the request for styles.css

Comment: @TiesonT. Hey Tieson, as a follow-up, I manged to make it work but to be completely honest with you I have no idea how, I removed the class selector and the style applied just fine, thanks for your time though, helped me figure out what .box was as well.

Comment: That _shouldn't_ have made a difference - a selector that doesn't match anything just gets ignored. It's possible that you had a syntax error or an old version of the stylesheet uploaded, and you just incidentally fixed the issue by updating it. Either way, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the path linking your CSS file. VSCODE makes it easy for you to check the path leading to your CSS file.

1. You can use intellisense to navigate to your target file
   `./` refers to the current directory.

`../` refers to the parent directory

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">`

2. You can navigate your CSS file and copy the relative path
   A. Right-click and click on the file
   B. Click on the Copy Relative Path Option
   C. Paste it right in the href tag
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the path to your styles.css file is correct relative to the HTML file. If the stylesheet is in the same directory as your HTML file, the path you provided should work. If it's in a different directory, you need to adjust the path accordingly.